# How to find 32-bit jvm.dll from a batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, jvm, 32bit-64bit

I've got a java app that I'm setting up as a Windows Service using [Procrun](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/procrun.html).  This app needs to use a 32-bit version of java because of one of the third party libraries used in the app.  I'm trying to write a batch script for users to be able to install the service, similar to [service.bat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Installing_services) in the tomcat bin directory.

Procrun uses a --Jvm parameter when installing a service.  This parameter can either be set to  auto or you can specify the full path to the jvm.dll.  I need to find a way to see if 32-bit java is installed and where that jvm.dll is located.

How can I find the 32-bit jvm.dll from a batch file?

I've seen similar questions that say to use java -version to see if its 32-bit or 64-bit, but just because the current version of java is 64-bit that doesn't mean they don't also have 32-bit installed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the answer you want.  But given that you want a particular type of JVM, wouldn't it be better to include it with your software and run off that?  Otherwise this seems something really hard to do from a batch file, since the JVM might be installed anywhere, and crawling through all files is probably not optimal.  You might be able to pull it off with Powershell, but then, not everyone has that installed either.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think this needs a complex solution,

just check the common paths for the jvm,

if its in "c:\Program Files(x86)\" then its the 32 bit version.
if its in "c:\Program Files" then its 64 bits.

you could also query regkeys, environment vars or the file itself with some thirdparty tool.
or even run a search over the whole system.
but try the simple solution first, maybe it works.

if you need help with the other ways to solve this just post it here :)

Answer (score 1):

If possible I'd go for the simple solution (i.e. guessing the binary type based on the installation directory). If it is not OK to be right most of the time, you could enumerate the runtimelib locations from the registry and then inspect the PE headers of the jvm.dll you found.

Below an example implementation in Powershell.

```
# Determine the machinetype of an executable

function Get-BinaryType {
param ($filename)

$PE_POINTER_OFFSET = 60;            
$MACHINE_OFFSET = 4;
$data = get-content $filename -encoding byte -totalcount 4096
$pe_header_addr = [BitConverter]::ToInt32($data, $PE_POINTER_OFFSET)
$machineUint = [BitConverter]::ToUint16($data, $pe_header_addr + $MACHINE_OFFSET)

$machineType = @{0 = "Native"; 0x014c = "I386"; 0x0200 = "Itanium"; 0x8664 = "x64"}
$machineType.Get_Item([int]$machineUint)

}

# Look for the value of the RuntimeLib value found under the JavaSoft registry
# keys and determine the binarytype of the file found under this value.

$registrykeys = "HKLM:\software\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft", "HKLM:\software\JavaSoft"
$registrykeys | Where-Object {test-path $_} | % {

  dir $_ -rec -ea SilentlyContinue |   
      ForEach-Object {   
      (get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath).RuntimeLib

   } | 
   select -Unique | 
   select @{N="Name";E={$_}}, @{N="BinaryType";E={Get-BinaryType $_}}
}
```